Leaflet: Markers only visible after zooming, how to make them always visible?
I have installed Leaflet and created a map with several markers. The map works correctly, but the markers are only visible when I zoom in. I want the markers to always be visible regardless of the zoom level. How can I achieve this?
Here’s a snippet of my code:
<template>
  <section class="py-16">
    <h1 class="text-5xl font-medium capitalize text-tfc-550 my-4 text-center">
      Sedi
    </h1>
    <section>
      <div v-if="isClient" class="w-full h-140" id="map">
      </div>
      <div v-else class="text-center text-gray-500">
        Caricamento della mappa in corso...
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue"

const isClient = ref(false)

onMounted(async () => {
  isClient.value = true

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const L = (await import("leaflet")).default
    //@ts-ignore
    await import("leaflet.markercluster")
    
    const map = L.map("map")
    
    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution: "&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors",
    }).addTo(map)

    const markers = L.markerClusterGroup()

    // Marker data
    const sedi = [
      { lat: 41.896852, lng: 12.481293, name: "Roma" },
      { lat: 45.532203, lng: 10.208898, name: "Brescia" },
      { lat: 45.483062, lng: 9.206098, name: "Milano" },
      { lat: 40.678369, lng: 14.765663, name: "Salerno" },
      { lat: 40.834449, lng: 14.229847, name: "Napoli" }
    ]

    sedi.forEach((sede) => {
      const marker = L.marker([sede.lat, sede.lng]).bindPopup(`<b>${sede.name}</b>`)
      markers.addLayer(marker) 
    })

    map.addLayer(markers)

    setTimeout(() => {
      const bounds = markers.getBounds()
      if (bounds.isValid()) {
        map.fitBounds(bounds)
      } else {
        console.error("Bounds non validi. Controlla i dati dei marker.")
      }
      map.invalidateSize()
      
    }, 100)
  }
})
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>

Here are my installed dependencies:
"dependencies": {
  "@nuxtjs/leaflet": "^1.2.6",
  "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.7.0",
  "@vueuse/core": "^10.7.2",
  "apexcharts": "^3.45.2",
  "glightbox": "^3.3.0",
  "gumshoejs": "^5.1.2",
  "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3",
  "lucide-vue-next": "^0.469.0",
  "nuxt": "^3.14.1592",
  "pinia": "^2.2.6",
  "preline": "^2.0.3",
  "swiper": "^11.0.6",
  "vue": "^3.5.13",
  "vue-router": "^4.5.0",
  "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.5.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.12.2",
  "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.9",
  "@tailwindcss/nesting": "^0.0.0-insiders.565cd3e",
  "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.15",
  "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
  "nuxt-anchorscroll": "^1.0.3",
  "postcss": "^8.4.49",
  "postcss-import": "^16.1.0",
  "prettier": "^3.3.3",
  "tw-colors": "^3.3.2"
}

Thank you in advance for your help!

It is similar to leaflet demo page example. I would suggest to add the markers themselves instead of several layers
  sedi.forEach((sede) => {
      const marker = L.marker([sede.lat, sede.lng]).addTo(map).bindPopup(`<b>${sede.name}</b>`)
      markers.addLayer(marker) 
    })


I am guessing that you just miss Leaflet.markercluster CSS file(s):
// After Leaflet CSS
import "leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css"
import "leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css"

Without these files, the Marker Cluster Group in your markers variable still builds clusters, but they may not be noticeable on the map, because only the number is shown, but not its colored circle.
And once you zoom in, the individual Markers may appear as they uncluster.
But if you do not want your Markers to be clustered at all, then simply do not use Leaflet.markercluster: either use a normal Layer Group instead, or directly add your Markers to the map, as suggested in v-g's answer (but do not add them as well into your markers group).
